# Samba on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - shared folder not accessible after reboot

Tags: samba

I've a strange problem with samba on a freshly setup machine using Ubuntu 22.04
I've installed and configured samba successfully to be used as a simple file server in my home network. I can access the shared folder (it's a folder on a different partition on the same physical SSD) from a different computer with Ubuntu on it and as well as from a Windows 10 machine, so far so good. However, after rebooting the server machine and being logged in, the shared folder is not accessible from my other computers. Samba service is running and loaded at startup. The weird thing is, in order to make it work, I just need to open Nautilus file explorer and navigate to the shared folder once. After that, the shared folder is immediately available and works perfectly again on the other machines. This behavior is reproducible on every reboot. Any suggestion how to get rid of this strange workaround?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: It sounds like you have not set up `/etc/fstab` to auto mount the partition where the shared folder lives. You may want to create a new mount point. Edit your question and add the partition format and the mounted folder location of the partition.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your fast reply. You are absolutely correct, the auto mount was not set up correctly. I've fixed the mount in the disk utility, now samba works after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The auto mount was not set up correctly. I've fixed the mount in the disk utility "Edit mount options" by switching off "User session defaults" and check "mount at system startup" and select the correct name under "identify as". Now samba works after reboot.

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution and posted the answer. If you could add a few screenshots of the disk utility window, the answer will be even better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a backup server rebuild from windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04. I had the shares setup and samba configured. No Shares after reboot. In Disks Utilities. I turned off the "User Session Defaults" Turned on "Mount at system Startup" and "Show in user interface". Then in file manager, under properties, I open the share I already had and re-shared it. Allow other and Guest are turned on for my in home LAN. I needed to do this for each share on each volume. Now the shares are there after reboot and work as expected.

Thank you for the information that help fix my problem.